# Do you use multiple SamplerStates for multiple Textures

Tags: directx, hlsl

If I am passing two textures into an HLSL shader, will I also need two SamplerState's? I am a little confused as to how the SamplerStates actually work. I never instantiate them or anything, I just call

```
Tex.Sample(sampler, pos);
```

I am compiling my shader for profile 9.3 (WP8 if that makes any difference)

Example Shader:

```
Texture2D InputTexture;
SamplerState Sampler;

float4 PSMain(float2 pos: TEXCOORD, float4 SVP : SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET {  
    float4 image = InputTexture.Sample(Sampler, pos);   
    return image;   
}

technique  {
    pass {
        Profile = 9.3;
        PixelShader = PSMain;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do is called multitexturing.

A [SamplerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604998.aspx) object contains the sampling and filtering options and the sampler allows you to read the data from the texture with that options.

There are many sampler states you can set:

```
Filter
AddressU
AddressV
AddressW
MipLODBias
MaxAnisotropy
ComparisonFunc
BorderColor
MinLOD
MaxLOD
```

In Direct3D 10 the syntax is the following:

```
//example
SamplerState mySampler{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR; //sets min/mag/mip filter to linear
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can find the default values and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb323488%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) some meanings of the states.

After all I can say that the number of `SamplerState`s you need depends on what kind of effect you want to achieve. But really simply your code could be like:

```
Texture2D InputTextures[2];
SamplerState Sampler;

float4 PSMain(float2 pos: TEXCOORD, float4 SVP : SV_POSITION) : SV_TARGET {
    float4 color = InputTexture[0].Sample(Sampler, pos) * InputTexture[1].Sample(Sampler, pos);
    return color;  
}
```

Infact as you can see you just need to multiply the two color of the textures to get a multitextured object.